# Real Analysis: why measure of irrational number intersect [0,1] is=1?

Tags: real-analysis

As the title states, why measure of irrational number intersect [0,1] is 1?

Intuition is enough

Comment: I think he is asking why $m(\mathbb{Q}^c\cap [0,1]) = 1$

Comment: When you ask "why", are you looking for an intuitive explanation, or a proof based on the definition of Lebesgue measure?

Comment: Sorry not union is intersect and intuition is enough

Comment: Perhaps it is better to explain  to yourself why $m(\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]) = 0$ instead.

Comment: Good call...got it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

observe that

$m(\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1])$ +  $m(\mathbb{Q}^c\cap[0,1])$ =  $m([0,1])$ 
and we know that  $m(\mathbb{Q}) = 0 $

therefore  $m(\mathbb{Q}^c\cap[0,1]) = 1 $